# how do I replace the default search engine at firefox mobile?

Tags: firefox

when I type some text at the url bar I see a few search engines available but the default one (the one used) when I press enter is verison, this is very annoying.

how can this be altered?

Answer (score 0):

Do the:

```
about:config
```

In URL bar, find one that says something about search engine, and then change it to whatever you like.

Comment: there's no such configuration.